# Maven multi-module project compile

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies

I created a C/S framework as a multi-module Maven project. It has three modules: "server", "client" and "common". Classes in "common" module are used both by "server" and "client".

However I don't want a standalone `common.jar`. Instead, I wish to compile classes in "common" module directly into `server.jar` and `client.jar`. Is there any way I can make it?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) to [unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies-mojo.html) the common jar into the other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use [maven assembly plugin with pre-defined descriptor jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies)

**Option 1:**
Include the following in the 'server' project pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

This will include other third party dependency as well, if you have any.

**Option 2:**
This option is to exclude third party libraries, if any.

1.Create an assembly.xml as follows in the same directory of pom.xml.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>custom</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <includes>
                <include>common</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

The include tag must contain `<groupId>:<artifactId>` format, here just the artifactId 'common' is mentioned as I don't know your groupId.

2.Include the following in the 'server' pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Run the assembly command (assembly:single).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this is to use the [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Add this to your server/client pom:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

You will end up with the `common` classes in the same jar as the `server`/`client`.